# Flask app slow if used by a small number of users in parallel

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-assets

I have a Flask app with a few simple Jinja2 templates. In addition I use Flask-Assets/pyScss for CSS.

If a single users works with the app then everything works great. If a small number of people (less than 20) access the app in parallel then the response time *sometimes* goes way up and it feels like the server is not responding at all.

I tried:

`ab -n 1000 -c 20 http://myapp`

But I wasn't able to reproduce the issue "artificially". How would you debug this kind of problem?

Comment: What is `b -n 1000 -c 20` doing?

Comment: @KarlBarker This was a typo. It is "ab" and this the Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool to run parallel requests: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running the development server (`app.run()`, or perhaps `./manage.py runserver` if using Flask-Script).  It runs one thread by default, and shouldn't be used in production even with threading enabled.  Instead, use a real application server such as [uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and proxy it behind a real web server such as [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/).  The [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/deploying/) directly tell you not to use the dev server in production, and list multiple examples of how to get started deploying it properly.